# Avoid proliferation of @MockBeans in Spring Boot @WebMvcTest test

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a simple controller e.g.

```
@Controller
public class FooController
{
    @Autowired
    private BarService barService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayFoo()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

When I want to do a `@WebMvcTest`, I have to create a great number of `@MockBeans` to prevent a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
@Import(WebSecurityConfig.class)
public class FooControllerTest
{
    @MockBean ...
    @MockBean ...
    @MockBean ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Does this mean that `BarService` is somehow creating a chain of dependencies? (it has some dependencies but some `@MockBean`s appear completely unrelated).

The problem is, is that each `@WebMvcTest` I add for different controllers also requires the same `@MockBean`s.

Should I be using an annotation like `@TestConfiguration` to specify all the `@MockBean`s for the DRY principal?

Comment: If FooController only depends on BarService as your code shows, you should only need one mock bean for BarService. A mock bean doesn't have any dependency: it's a mock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at this again, and found you can pass the controller name to `@WebMvcTest` e.g. `@WebMvcTest(FooController.class)`.

> Specifies the controllers to test. May be left blank if all {@code
>   @Controller} beans should be added to the application context.

Answer (score 1):

As Hal8k said, if you don't specify a controller like `@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)`, it will try to load all `@Controller` components. And `@Import(WebSecurityConfig.class)` also try to inject components in `WebSecurityConfig.class`.

Refer : https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when the bean scanning configuration is faulty or excessive.

In my case, I was still getting the error despite having specified the controller to test in `@WebMvcTest(FooController.class)`.

I eventually realised it was due to the `@ComponentScan` of my application being needlessly cluttered up. My Application.java was something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"fr.nevechris.projectname","fr.nevechris.projectname.otherpackage"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I removed the `@ComponentScan` entirely and the issue was solved.

If your `@ComponentScan` is good or not specified, try searching for other places in your project where configuration is done (eg `@Configuration` tag).